# Integrating Facebook php SDK in a plugin

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to add the Facebook php SDK as part of a custom plugin I'm building for a CMS (very similar to CodeIgniter).

The problem I'm getting is that the classes don't seem to be loaded.

My file structure is:

```
PluginFolder
 - customClassFile.php
 + librairies
   - autoload.php (Facebook's automatic loading)
   + Facebook folder that contains all the SDK
```

As for code, I've simplified it to this:

```
//customClassFile.php
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/libraries/autoload.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;

class CustomClass {
  public function __construct() {

    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('appId', 'secret_key');
  }
}
```

In the `autoload.php` file I know it's finding the classes because I echoed something after

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    echo('found');
    require $file;
}
```

I've tried many other stuff but this seems to be the more logical and I still get an error saying that `FacebookSession` could not be found.

The framework I'm using is Wolf CMS but you probably never heard of it. Like I said, it's similar to CodeIgniter.

This is the important part of my error stack

```
spl_autoload_call('Facebook\FacebookSession')  on line 13 in [...]
    AutoLoader→load('Facebook\FacebookSession')  on line unknown in unknown
```

It's probably related to namespaces but I can't figure it out.
Thank you for your time.